# nested map function of functools subpress one line

Tags: python, list, functional-programming

I wonder that is there any fancy way for nested map function.

example code is like below

```
import functools 
y1 = [1,2]
y2 = [3,4]
y3 = [5,6]
alldata = [y1,y2,y3]
result = map(lambda f : map(lambda s : s*10 , f) , alldata)
```

and i want to change this part for readable code

```
result = map(lambda f : map(lambda s : s*10 , f) , alldata)
```

Comment: A list comprehension may be more readable, but I think your current code is about as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

You current code is good, but if you consider Python's syntax for anonymous functions a bit heavy, you could use a list-comprehension or, if you want to preserve `map`'s laziness, a generator comprehension.

```
y1 = [1,2]
y2 = [3,4]
y3 = [5,6]
alldata = [y1, y2, y3]

result = ((x * 10 for x in data) for data in alldata)

for data in result:
    print(*data)
```

Output:

```
10 20
30 40
50 60
```